# how to convert a cc_binary to cc_library?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, openssl, bazel

I have some sample code on openssl which I found on the documentation. (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption under C++ section)

They suggested to compile with

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 aes_binary.cxx -o aes_binary.exe -lcrypto
```

I adapted this into bazel as:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "aes_binary",
    srcs = ["aes_binary.cpp"],
    deps = ["//base"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lcrypto"
    ]
)
```

It works fine but I want to convert this into a library. The code basically contains a template class, and 3 functions (encrypt, decrypt, genparams). I separated the binary into aes.h and aes.cpp and want to use this library in other modules and binaries.

```
c_library(
    name = "aes",
    hdrs = ["aes.h"],
    srcs = ["aes.cpp"],
)
```

and imported this in another binary which has:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "vulndb_miner",
    srcs = ["vulndb_miner.cpp"],
    deps = ["//codelearn/vulndb:aes",
            ],
    linkopts = [
        "-lcrypto",
    ]
)
```

However, it does not compile saying that
'OPENSSL_cleanse' was not declared in this scope
'EVP_add_cipher' was not declared in this scope

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I include the library in vulndb_miner.cpp as #include "codelearn/vulndb/aes.h"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user of `aes` target needs to link to the `crypto` lib, thus you should add your `linktopt` here:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "aes",
    hdrs = ["aes.h"],
    srcs = ["aes.cpp"],
    linkopts = ["-lcrypto"]
)
```

By the way it is better to compile as much as you can with Bazel, because it makes your build reproductible and hermetic: you do not depends anymore on system-wide OpenSSL.

For example [boringssl](https://github.com/google/boringssl) is good replacement for OpenSSL, if you use Bazel:

```py
# WORKSPACE file
http_archive(
    name = "boringssl",
    strip_prefix = "boringssl-16100fd5073b3986ca03efa6bbb501c2e061e7e3"
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/boringssl/archive/16100fd5073b3986ca03efa6bbb501c2e061e7e3.zip"],
)

# BUILD file
cc_library(
    name = "aes",
    hdrs = ["aes.h"],
    srcs = ["aes.cpp"],
    deps= ["@boringssl//:ssl"]
)
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it but I can not include the boringssl files somehow. I tried
#include <boringssl/src/include/openssl/rand.h> and    
#include "boringssl/src/include/openssl/rand.h"

both say no such file or directory

Comment: Just try `#include <openssl/rand.h>`